# T-SQL Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql

```
IF (SELECT begin_date FROM reservation WHERE id=@id) <=@end_date
AND
(SELECT end_date FROM reservation WHERE id=@id) >= @begin_date
BEGIN
    PRINT 'already reserved'
    RETURN
END
```

This is IF statement in my stored procedure. I have multiple reservations and I want to check if they don't intersect with the one I want to add. The problem is how to compare multiple values returned by query with variable?

Comment: You should put `MIN` or `MAX` on begin_date and end_date.

Comment: But I want to compare it with all future reservations, not only one

Comment: Have you try my answer below?

Comment: What is the @id and why are you using it as a parameter?

Comment: @Ala That was stored procedure. So I guess, ID refers to reservation id based on user-input, and begin_date/end_date as well.

Comment: @RubahMalam, yes I tried it, but it also denies the dates between two reservations.

Comment: @Ala it is the id of car in reservation table. It is a parameter of procedure

Comment: @TomaszKal, okay that makes sense. I posted the answer that you need.

Comment: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Do you _really_ need a solution that works for both `sql-server` and `mysql`?

Comment: @HABO it's first time I ask question on stack overflow, thanks for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your logic for "already reserved" is correct based on your query, then this should do what you want

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT *
           FROM reservation rsv1
           WHERE rsv1.id=@id
             AND rsv1.begin_date <=@end_date
             AND rsv1.end_date >= @begin_date)
BEGIN
PRINT 'already reserved'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put MIN or MAX on begin_date and end_date. something like this :

```
IF (SELECT MIN(begin_date) FROM reservation WHERE id=@id) <=@end_date
AND
(SELECT MAX(end_date) FROM reservation WHERE id=@id) >= @begin_date
BEGIN
    PRINT 'already reserved'
    RETURN
END
```

Comment: What if it is okay to book a time between the beginning of the first event and the end of the last event already stored in the database?